# How to scroll automatically to the center in iframe within a handler?

Tags: html, iframe, handler, href, autoscroll

I have this code

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_surveys&amp;Itemid=120&amp;act=view_survey&amp;survey=1:basic-survey" class="modal" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 680, y: 500}}">Click here</a>​
```

and i need to use this code, no way around it. i have gone crazy looking for a way to make THIS CODE scroll the iframe to the middle of the page. please help. I never used an iframe within a handler and using the modal class like that, i don't know where the parameters will go, or even what parameter will go. i tried a few with no success.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

You're question is unclear....do you need to scroll to a point on the page with the click of a button? If so use to scrollWindow/scrollTo function, e.g.:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollWindow()
{
window.scrollTo(100,500);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="scrollWindow()" value="Scroll" />
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to align the iframe to the centre, use a table, e.g.:

```
<body> 
<table width="100%" height="100%"> 
  <tr align="center"> 
    <td align="30px"> 
         <div id="iframe" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:100%; height:100%;">
         Insert iframe code here</div>

    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table> 

</body>
```